# conditional tag and its performace in wordpress

Tags: performance, wordpress, tags, conditional-statements

i just know is this conditional tag have good performance in a big scaled website ?

```
((in_array('vlc2' , get_terms( 'VLC Player', array('fields' => 'names'))) 
AND 'softwares' == get_post_type()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You question is difficult to answer, in general, you should consider:

- How large is the array `vlc2`?
- get_terms will query to database, can you avoid that?
- get_post_type() Retrieve the post type of the current post or of a given post.
     this should be ok.

Comment: thanks again bingjie2680 , 
1. the vlc2 is assigned to many posts/custom posts.
2. no i have not any idea to use another conditional to replace by currently assigned.
3.the Current Post_type

Comment: well. the performance should not be so bad in here. one way to optimize it is to avoid the database query. otherwise, can't help it.